# Mac Console paste generating trash text

Tags: macos, console, copy-paste

On mac os console, when doing paste of large quantities of text (for example an sql database) I get loads of trash and corrupted text. But when doing the same under windows or into a text box, this doesn't happen and the text comes out ok.

Is this a buffer problem or something like it? If so anyone know any flag to make its size bigger?

Other than that, anyone got any sugestiong on a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use copy/paste.  Seriously, the shell was designed a long time before the GUI; it doesn't well with certain modern HIG idioms like copy/paste.  The ironic thing is that your task will probably be *easier* if you dump to a temporary file rather than pasting.  For example, rather than doing something like this:

```
dump_database
# select and hit Cmd+C
create_database
# hit Cmd+V at prompt
```

Try something more like the following:

```
dump_database | create_database
```

Or if you absolutely must:

```
dump_database > tmp_file
# ...
create_database < tmp_file
rm tmp_file
```

**Alternatively:** Just use [`pbcopy` and `pbpaste`](http://osxdaily.com/2007/03/05/manipulating-the-clipboard-from-the-command-line/).